# SQL: Combine fields without repetition

Tags: sql

I have a table that has price history for several items -

```
Item   Date    Price
  X   1Jan13    100
  X   2Jan13    110
 ...
  X   31Dec13   115
  Y   1Jan13     50
  Y   2Jan13     47
 ...
  Y   31Dec13    58
```

and so on.

I have just written a query to find out the dates for which the prices of a particular item does not change for three consecutive days. Using two inner joins my query returns the output in the following format -

```
Item   Date1     Date2     Date3  Price
 X    2Jun13    3Jun13    4Jun13   110
 X    3Jun13    4Jun13    5Jun13   110
 ...
 X    29Dec13   30Dec13   31Dec13  125
 Y    29Mar13   30Mar13   31Mar13  55
```

Now, my question is how can I get the output in following format

```
Item  Date     Price
 X    2Jun13    110
 X    3Jun13    110
 X    4Jun13    110
 X    5Jun13    110
 X    29Dec13   125
 X    30Dec13   125
 X    31Dec13   125
```

and so on for all the items. That is, how can I combine/merge three date fields (without repetition) to generate a single date field? Because as you can see the desired format is easier to read compared to what I am getting right now.

Here is the code that I used for my query:

```
Select x.* 
From (
      Select T1.ItemName As Item, T1.Date As Date_3, T2.Date As Date_2, T3.Date As Date_1,
      Round((T1.Price - T2.Price), 2) As Change, Round((T1.Price - T3.Price), 2) As Change_2, T1.Price As Price
      From MarketData As T1 Inner Join MarketData As T2 On T1.ItemName = T2.ItemName 
      Inner Join MarketData As T3 On T2.ItemName = T3.ItemName
      Where (T1.Date = T3.Date + 2 Or (DatePart(DW, T3.Date) In (5, 6) And T1.Date = T3.Date + 4)) And 
     (T2.Date = T3.Date + 1 Or (DatePart(DW, T3.Date) = 6 And T2.Date = T3.Date + 3))
 ) As x
Where x.Change = 0 And x.Change_2 = 0
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and tell us which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database support unions, you can do like this:

```
select Item, Date, Price from
(
select Item, Date1 as Date, Price from (<1st select here>) res
union
select Item, Date2 as Date, Price from (<1st select here>) res
union
select Item, Date3 as Date, Price from (<1st select here>) res
) table
order by Date
```

you can also transform <1st select here> in a subquery and further otimize the sql.

EDIT: here's with your query included, I obviously didn't try it, but hope it will help :)

```
select table.Item, table.Date, table.Price from
(
select Item, Date1 as Date, Price from tdp res
union
select Item, Date2 as Date, Price from tdp res
union
select Item, Date3 as Date, Price from tdp res
) table,
(Select x.* 
From (
      Select T1.ItemName As Item, T1.Date As Date_3, T2.Date As Date_2, T3.Date As Date_1,
      Round((T1.Price - T2.Price), 2) As Change, Round((T1.Price - T3.Price), 2) As Change_2, T1.Price As Price
      From MarketData As T1 Inner Join MarketData As T2 On T1.ItemName = T2.ItemName 
      Inner Join MarketData As T3 On T2.ItemName = T3.ItemName
      Where (T1.Date = T3.Date + 2 Or (DatePart(DW, T3.Date) In (5, 6) And T1.Date = T3.Date + 4)) And 
     (T2.Date = T3.Date + 1 Or (DatePart(DW, T3.Date) = 6 And T2.Date = T3.Date + 3))
 ) As x
Where x.Change = 0 And x.Change_2 = 0) as tdp
order by Date
```

Comment: Is there a way I could just use 'x' in place of <1st select here>, instead of copying the entire query three times? Where x has the results from my query, please see the code for my query above if this is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: To avoid copying the query three times, you can use a "common table expression" (WITH query AS ...) or a temporary table.